# How can I update my game?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

My game's version is 1.3.2. How can I update to the latest version. Will it delete my saves if I do?

Comment: Updating shouldn't delete saves, but they may become incompatible with the new version. Unless you pirated the game (buying it on steam, the windows store or the official website) it should keep itself up to date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You received an email when you bought Game Dev Tycoon via FastSpring. 
In that email, you have multiple download links. Just redownload the game and reinstall it.
That is all you need to do.

Alternatively, you could activate your game via Steam and enjoy the automatic updating there. You should have received an email with your Steam Key a while ago.

Answer (score 2):

If you bought the game through Windows Store on Windows 8(.1), Windows should keep it up-to-date automatically. If not, check the updates page in the Store.

Answer (score 1):

No it wont delete your saves I helped my friend with this so it's ok to update!:D

Comment: When creating answers, please answer the *whole* question. How can you update Game Dev Tycoon to the latest version?